# How to get the date when an entity was persisted

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

I want to sort a celltable by the last ones added on top, now , to do this, i need to sort them by the date they were added to the application. Is there a way to get this date? or i have to create a new attribute for each class?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own attribute.

Comment: Yes, i did it this ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding well, you can use a comparator. For example, suppose you have some clas into gwt.shared.model package such as:

```
public class SomeClass implements IsSerializable {

    private Date date;   

    // some stuff...

}
```

Then, implement a comparator for that class

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SomeClassComparator implements Comparator<SomeClass> {

@Override
public int compare(SomeClass someObject1, SomeClass someObject2) {
        if (someObject1.getDate().getTimeInMillis() > someObject2.getDate().getTimeInMillis()) return 1
        else if someObject1.getDate().getTimeInMillis() > someObject2.getDate().getTimeInMillis() return 0;
        else return 0;
}

}
```

Before adding objects into the table you must do:

```
List<SomeClass> someObjects = ... // list of objects
Collection.sort(someObjects);
```

Then you can show them in the cell table.

**Edit 1:** the comparator must be included in gwt.shared.model

Comment: This is great, but i had to implement Comparable, instead of Comparator. It seams that Collections.sort() is for comparable when you have vectors to sort.

Comment: Got it (I think), you are trying to give comparable behavior rather than sort the instances by a method, could it be?